# Set Status bar in AppDelegate?

Tags: swift, xcode, statusbar, appdelegate

Previously, I had this code and it worked perfectly before Swift was updated. Now it says:

> Setter for '**statusBarStyle**' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[**UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle**]

Now, I read that you have to override the `statusBarStyle` but I don't want to do this manually in each `UIViewController` but instead, control it via a `struct` and an `extension` of the `UIApplication`. Not sure how to do that though.

**The code:**

```
extension UIApplication {
    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }
}


struct StatusBar {

    static func setStatusBar() {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        if let currentVC = appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController?.getCurrentlyDisplayedVC() {
            if currentVC is LoginVC || currentVC is SignUpVC || currentVC is SignUpVC {
                UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = .clear
            }
            else {
                UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = Colors.mainBlueColor
            }
        }
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    }
}



extension UIViewController {

    func getCurrentlyDisplayedVC() -> UIViewController {

        if let presentedVC = presentedViewController {
            return presentedVC.getCurrentlyDisplayedVC()
        }
        else if let split = self as? UISplitViewController, let last = split.viewControllers.last {
            return last.getCurrentlyDisplayedVC()
        }
        else if let nav = self as? UINavigationController, let top = nav.topViewController {
            return top.getCurrentlyDisplayedVC()
        }
        else if let tab = self as? UITabBarController {

            if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return selected.getCurrentlyDisplayedVC()
            }
        }
        return self
    }
}
```